# Displacement fields

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensors, classical-mechanics

Given the following equation:
$$ \partial_t  e = \sigma : \partial_t D u $$
The double point is the product of tensors, $e$ is the internal energy, $\sigma$ the Cauchy stress tensor and $Du$ the infinitesimal strain tensor. I'm looking for an adequat field of displacement $u$ such that it follows from the equation that $e$ only depends on $Du$. Is this possible? What could be an example for such a field?

Comment: What do you mean by  $\sigma : \partial_t D u$?

Comment: @DMan:  you mean like $\partial_t e = \frac{\sigma}{\partial_t Du}$?

Comment: @RobertLewis The double point means the product of tensors, $e$ is the internal energy, $\sigma$ the Cauchy stress tensor and $Du$ the infinitesimal strain tensor.

Comment: @Harry49 You're absolutely right! :-)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?